# Maximum norm strictly positive solution of $Ax=b$ (underdetermined set of linear equations)?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

We all know the leastsquares (minimum $\mathcal{L_2}$ norm) solution to a full rank set of underdetermined equations is well known as $x_p = A^+ b$ where $A^+ $ is the Moore -penrose inverse.

Is there a "maximum norm " positive solution as well? Can it be written analytically ?

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions of arbitrarily large norm. The solutions are of the form $x_p + w$ where $w \in \text{nullspace}(A)$, and $w$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: ah, that right. I am looking for only positive solutions.  In this case, the space is bounded and there should exist a maximum norm solution, right?

Also, I find this a bit confusing  -the standard derivation for the least-squares solution (that ends up defining the pseudoinverse)  should be the same for the "maximum norm " solution as well ?

Comment: @NadaBrothers Not necessarily (for example if the nullspace contains some vector with nonnegative entries).

Comment: What if we add a constraint that the sum of the elements of $x$ is equal to a given value, i.e. $x^T 1 = c$?  Thank you